# ComboSelection MaterialUI ReactJs Api Data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react and I am using material ui (components) combobox to display selected data from an API.

This is my code:

```
this.state = { data: [] , dataValue: ''}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllData().then(data => this.setState({data})}

 render() {
     return (
         <FormControl variant="filled">
         <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-age-native-simple">DATA</InputLabel>
  <Select
   native
   value={this.state.dataValue}
   onChange={this.handleChange('dataValue')}
   input={<FilledInput name="dataValue" id="filled-age-native-simple" />}>
   // Problem solved
  {this.state.data.map(dataV => {
      return (
            <option value={dataV.id}> {dataV.name} </option>
          );
    })}

   </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Each time you select a value, an id is assigned to the state.

By implementing this, I get this error:

> Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Select`, expected a ReactNode.
>   in Select (created by Context.Consumer)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise state - you can only do this with values to hand, so to speak. You cannot use a promise based value, like you are trying to do:

```
this.state = { data: this.props.getAllData(), dataValue: ''}
```

Secondly, when you render components, you also need to have all the data to hand to render. Specifically, you cannot do this:

```
render() {
    return <el>{this.state.data.then(...
```

If you need to handle async data calls in your component, you should use the componentDidMount function (or constructor) to initiate the call.

For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getMyData().then(data => this.setState({data}) )
}
```

In calling setState, this will trigger a rerender of your component and can make use of the data you just stored in state.

Comment: I done the changes, tried to set the options value like this {this.state.data.map(dataV => {<option value{dataV.id}> {dataV.name} </option>})} but the option values are empty, what could be the problem? not renders the data into options?

Comment: typo perhaps? value={dataV.id}

Comment: I tried, even declaring <option value={1}>Test</option> inside the map, still is empty.

Comment: ok then probably your data array is empty - console.log(this.state.data) in your render function to inspect

Comment: I did, it gets empty, empty, empty then with data, which is weird.

Comment: that's expected - your component will render a few times before the data is available. Then the last time should be when your data is there.

Comment: the last array contains data, It is because the options takes just the first array which is empty?

Comment: no the component should update with each rerender - but I can't help you without seeing your new code - perhaps create a new question with your new code

Comment: what is the exact contents of this.state.data then?

Comment: I fixed the problem  and I will update the code with the fixed problem.

Comment: ok please mark as correct since I fixed your original problem.